# How to obey DRY with @user_passes_test when passing path to login_url

Tags: django

How do i pass my login page from `urls.py` to the `login_url` variable in `@user_passes_test`. Basically `reverse_*` does not work, neither does `resolve_url`.

Since i have made my own login system, i am not able to let the function reverse automatically to `accounts/*`.

```
# view
@login_required    
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='Therapist').count() == 0, login_url='reverse('admin_user_login'))
def index_view(request):
    """
    Index view after login.
    """
    template_name = "adminApp/page/index.html"
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name)

# urls
url(r'^login/$', views.user_login_view, name='admin_user_login'),
```

Comment: You might want to modify the settings.LOGIN_URL variable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url

Comment: I have multiple LOGIN_URL's so this is not really feasible in my use-case.

Comment: Which django version do you use? reverse seems to be buggy in < 1.3 (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5925)

Comment: Well, than I assume that there's something else wrong with your code (something different from the quote before reverse). Are you using url namespaces (reverse('accounts:admin_user_login'))?

If you don't find the error, you could copy the user_passes_test decorator [1] and debug it manually.

[1] https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py

Comment: I have tried with namespaces, but unfortunately that did not work either.. U